# BeautifulSoup does not find text within tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

It looks very simple but I don't find the mistake and I have been spending a few hours on this now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

txt = "<HTML><BODY><TABLE><TR><TD><P>Net sales</P></TD></TR></TABLE></BODY></HTML>"
print(txt)
bs = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')
q = bs.find(tag='p', text='Net sales')
# table = q.find_parent('table')
print("q = ", q)
```

This results (in Jupyter) in

```
<HTML><BODY><TABLE><TR><TD><P>Net sales</P></TD></TR></TABLE></BODY></HTML>
q =  None
```

Why is the text 'Net sales' not found?

Finally I want to get the text within the table-tag, I just commented that line in the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without using the 'tag' argument

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = "<HTML><BODY><TABLE><TR><TD><P>Net sales</P></TD></TR></TABLE></BODY></HTML>"
bs = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')
print bs
q = bs.find('p', text='Net sales')
# table = q.find_parent('table')
print("q = ", q)
```

**Output:**

```
('q = ', <p>Net sales</p>)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works! But shouldn't it also work with the tag-argument?

Comment: I dnt think tag is a valid argument name.